# SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"x.x.x.x\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh

Tags: ansible

This error happened. Please let me know how to fix it

```
fatal: [158.69.79.128]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"158.69.79.128\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", 
    "unreachable": true
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/devsoft/work/hikster/deploy/dev.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
158.69.79.128              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: can you ssh to that machine from the host? did you define in your inventory the user/pass to connect via ssh?

Comment: I can connect server using ssh,but anysible-playbook doen' t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines in ansible.cfg

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh = smart
transfer_method = smart
```